# How to authenticate WIFI network key?

Tags: android, networking, wifi, android-wifi

I have list of available WIFI near me. I want to connect specific wifi. How to authenticate with particular WIFI that I have selected.

After selecting one of the listed wifi and entering the password of the same how to verify the password entered is same as set by the host. How the data will be compared by the data set by host ?

[image: List of WIFI available near me]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create one broadcast register for that which will fire the broadcast intent if it detects any changes in wifi state.

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
```

create one local broadcast which listen for this update.
e.g.

```
 BroadcastReceiver WifiChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null && action.equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "onReceive: \"wifi connected:\" " + networkInfo.isConnected());
            if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                if (wifiInfo.getSSID().contains("your desired SSID")/*("Android")*/) {
                    isAllowed = true;
                    Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "==============================onReceive: " + isAllowed);

                    Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "onReceive:connected to wifi " + wifiInfo.getSSID());
                } else {
                    Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "onReceive:connected to wifi " + wifiInfo.getSSID());
                    isAllowed = false;
                }

            }
        }
    }
};
```

if you got the wifi connected that means you've passed right credentials
otherwise it's false